# dimension of subspace of the vector space of polynomials of degree atmost $20$

Tags: linear-algebra

$V=\large P_{20}(x)$ and $W_1=\{p\in V:p(1/2)=p(7)=p(5)=p(1)=0\}$

$W_2=\{p\in V:p(1/2)=p(7)=p(3)=p(4)=0\}$

We need to find $\dim W_1\cap W_2$

$\dim V=21$, Can I say $\dim W_1=\dim W_2=4$? I need hint to solve this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Rather $\dim W_1=\dim W_2=21-4=17$.

**Hint:** Of which polynomials $W_1\cap W_2$ consists?

Comment: $W_1\cap W_2=\{p: p(1/2)=p(7)=0\}$

Comment: So $\dim (W_1\cap W_2)=15$ ?

Comment: Could you tell me where we are using rank nulity theorem?

Comment: No, $W_1\cap W_2=\{p\in V:p(1/2)=p(7)=p(5)=p(1)=p(3)=p(4)=0\}$.

Comment: I do not understand, please explain elaborately

Comment: What explain? The last comment?

Comment: If $p\in W_1$ it has roots $1/2,7,5,1$. If $p\in W_2$ it has roots $1/2,7,3,4$. So if $p\in W_1\cap W_2$ it has roots $1/2,7,5,1,3,4$.

Comment: @BorisNovikov can you please explain me how $dim W_1=dimW_2=17$?